# Program to convert a string to integer

Tags: c, arrays, string

The code I have written is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
int strToint(char []);
int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter the string-");
    gets(str);
    printf("\nthe integer is %d ",strToint(str));
    return 0;
}
int strToint(char str[])
{
    int i,a,sum=0,k,j;
    a=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        k=str[i]-'0';
        j=pow(10,a-i-1);
        sum+=k*j;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If I enter the input as, say 567, I get 562 but I do not see why. I feel this is probably related to the pow function.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you simply can use aoit function for this conversion... sum=atoi(str);

Comment: I get a correct answer: http://ideone.com/4Ae89x

Comment: For input "567" i get output 567 with your code. Everything seems to work.

Comment: What's wrong with `sscanf`? And why would you call `strlen()` and so iterate over the string twice? And why call `pow()` which is a floating point function. Use integer arithmetic if you must do this. And what if your string doesn't contain all digit characters?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://i58.tinypic.com/2hdteua.png . Any idea what's happening? :/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I know I can do it without the pow() function but still I am curious about why the above code fails to work on my system. Thanks!

Comment: @PranavArora you can always try to step through the code with a debugger and see which line does something that you did not expect

Comment: @PranavArora Are you certain "567" --> "562" and not something like "467", "557", or "566"?

Comment: @chux: Nope, I have attached a screenshot in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

`pow()` is a floating point function and its behaviour varies from system to system. There's no requirement placed by the standard on its accuracy. It seems that yours is not returning values with the accuracy that you would require.

You do not need to implement functions to convert text to integer since the standard library contains functions that do that. An obvious choice would be `sscanf`.

But if you must implement such a function, you should use integer arithmetic. Any such code should handle negative values, and check for invalid input. For instance. What happens when you pass `"a"` to your function?

Comment: Thanks David! I have made the code assuming that the user enters a valid input.

Comment: `pow` is required to return `1.0` if the second argument is `0`. So it seems that this is not a conforming C implementation.

Comment: @Jens I rather imagined that it was the other calls to pow that would fail. All the same, floating point is wrong here.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Confident OP's `pow()` did return `1.0` with `pow(10,0)`, but returned `99.9999..` on `pow(10,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and got the expected result. Maybe the problem is related with function pow.

You could write the function simpler without using functions that deal with real numbers.

For example

```
int strToint( const char str[] )
{
    int sum = 0;

    for ( ; *str; ++str )
    {
        sum = 10 * sum + *str - '0';
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Take into account that function `gets` is unsafe. It is better to use function `fgets`. For example

```
fgets( str, 20, stdin );

size_t n = strlen( str );
if ( str[n - 1] == '\n' ) str[n - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you again, I did not know about `fgets`. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the first call to `pow(10,2)` the library's weak `pow()` returns 99.999... which is truncated to 99 on assignment to `j`.

Since the first digit is 5, the final sum is 5 less.  (100*5 vs 99*5)

If code *must* use FP functions, best to round before integer assignment

```
j = round(pow(10,...));
```

As @Vlad points out, all FP math can be avoided.

--

Floating point functions are not required by C to be accurate.  A *good* `pow()` function though should have provided an exact answer here, that is why it worked on so many other machines.

For a complete atoi, there are many posts, such as [FromStringToInteger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64049/29485)